# drawing on CandlestickSeries LineSeries makes candles narrower

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts, flex4.5, candlestick-chart

I'm, using Flex 4.5. 
In my application I have a CandlestickChart with basic CandlestickSeries.
I give the user the ability to add a linechart on top of the candlesChart by adding a LineSeries to the CandleStickChart as explained in adobe's docs here: [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c4f.html)

My problem is that when the line is added it changes the shape of the candle to be narrower. Moreover, every line that is added is making the candle be narrower.

I've looked around and found this thread in adobe's forums: ["CandlestickChart problem with  LineSeries"](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4095074) which describes the exact same problem.

Unfortunately, the thread is still not answered.

Does any one knows a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Ravid

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution I found is not nice and better solutions are still appreciated but for those of you that have the same problem this solution worked for me:

The problem occurs because the candle's default item renderer uses the item's width to calculate the size of the candle which is make sense. 
The problem, is that when you add another series there is a bug and the item's width is changed thefore the candle is changed.

My solution is to create a copy of the default item renderer and draw the candles based on the graph's width and number of candles you wish to put there (so you don't use the item's width).

It fixes the problem but if you use tooltips functionality than it kinda messes its placement relative to the candle.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a bit late, but in case it helps anyone else, here's what I did.
(It's not thoroughly tested either)

Make a class that extends the CandleStickChart class and simply override the "applySeriesSet" function as so:

```
override protected function applySeriesSet(seriesSet:Array /* of Series */,
                                               transform:DataTransform):Array /* of Series */
    {
        // filter out the non-candlestick series
        var filteredSeriesSet:Array = new Array();
        for each(var series:Series in seriesSet){
            if(series is CandlestickSeries) filteredSeriesSet.push(series);
        }

        // call the CandlestickChart applySeriesSet function with the filtered set, ignore return value
        super.applySeriesSet(filteredSeriesSet, transform);

        // do the code that the CartesianChart applySeriesSet function would have done, but with the unfiltered seriesSet 
        // would have preferred to do something like super.super.applySeriesSet(seriesSet, transform);
        var n:int = seriesSet.length;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var newSeries:IChartElement = seriesSet[i];
            if (newSeries is Series)
                customizeSeries(Series(seriesSet[i]), i);
        }
        return seriesSet;
    }
```